# writing Beautiful Soup output to a file

Tags: io, beautifulsoup, information-retrieval

Okay so I'm having an issue writing the extracted information I want to file.  I tested this with a simple print statement and its giving the exact output I want.  However. when I attempt to write this information to a file it writes nothing and the file shows up empty

The input is a wiki file in XML format and a list of strings corresponding to the page titles I wish to pull out of the wiki file.  Here is the code, where page_titles is an list like ['Anarchism','Adam and Eve', ...] :

```
new_wiki = open('new_wiki.xml', 'w')
soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki)
wiki_page = soup.find_all('page')
for item in wiki_page:
  title = item.title.get_text()
  if title in page_titles:
    new_wiki.write('\n' % (item))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but did you just forget `new_wiki.close()`?